# Load image using ng-src in android ionic aplication

Tags: android, image, ionic-framework, src

I'm developing an application using ionic, iOS, and Android, too. I have to load external images using `ng-src` at url:

http://test.url.eu:1337/fileuploads/receive/552f6d1786a3ea3772000004

It works fine on iOS, but on android I have unsafe error and the image is not loaded.
How can I can fix this?

EDIT:
It works on android 4.4 and 5 but not for < 4.4. I'm using crosswolk.. thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem where the app worked great on PC but 404's on android.
Depending on your Cordova version, as seen at Cordova Android 4.0.0 announcement, since Cordova 4.0.0 it could be you must add the cordoba-

> Whitelist functionality is revamped
>
> - You will need to add the new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to continue using a whitelist
> - Setting a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported and is the recommended way to whitelist (see details in plugin readme)
> - Network requests are blocked by default without the plugin, so install this plugin even to allow all requests, and even if you are using CSP.
> - This new whitelist is enhanced to be more secure and configurable, but
>     the Legacy whitelist behaviour is still available via a separate plugin (not recommended).
> - Note: while not strictly part of this release, the latest default app created by cordova-cli will include this plugin by default.

To install: `Cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`.

After this you'll need to add the mandatory content security policy: (a simple one to try out is: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`
but i would recommend reading about the options at http://content-security-policy.com).
Don't forget to check your *config.xml* for defining access origin (simplest is `<access origin="*"/>`). If still does not work have a look at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#navigation-whitelist to see if you require navigation or intent white-listing.
Good luck!

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't work.. i'm using crosswolk for android.. in logcat i can see: Refused to load the script 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js' .. i think there is again something that stops my internet connection.. it works on android 4.4 and android 5 but no on android <4.4 ..