# ionic cordova not load data from server on devices

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic application development. I am just using ionic sample project from their site. But the problem is that it works fine in browser. But not load data from server on device.

Error message shows

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What are you trying? It looks like the server isn't getting the requests properly.

Comment: Google, setting proxy for live reload on your device. I probably think its a cross domain issue.

Comment: If server is running in localhost, try giving your ip in the url where the connection to server is specified.

Comment: Thanks,its not the error in the code.because code is working code which i downloaded from a working sample project.the problem i think is in ionic install.or when i update cordova to 5.0

Comment: Okay, so like Ophir linked you to an answer, you should try adding the plugin. I recently answered a question here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29916802/4412363. Let me know if the same steps works for you.

Answer (score 7):

Given I can't just add comment (sad but true), I'll use a full blown answer.
Take a look at the answer I published here, looks like it could be the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29953668/4509672

Highlights from it:

> Depending on your Cordova version, as seen at Cordova
>   Android 4.0.0 announcement, since Cordova 4.0.0 it could be you must
>   add the cordoba-
>
> Whitelist functionality is revamped
>
> - You will need to add the new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to
>     continue using a whitelist
> - Setting a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported and is the recommended way to whitelist (see details in plugin readme)
> - Network requests are blocked by default without the
>     plugin, so install this plugin even to allow all requests, and even if
>     you are using CSP.
> - This new whitelist is enhanced to be more secure
>     and configurable, but the Legacy whitelist behaviour is still
>     available via a separate plugin (not recommended).
> - Note: while not
>     strictly part of this release, the latest default app created by
>     cordova-cli will include this plugin by default.

Comment: I have no idea why you got a down-vote earlier. But after a day of finding nothing I finally hit your post and my problems were solved!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: To tell you the truth, I don't really know either, but having the same problem in the past I know it was a pain, and its great to hear it solved yours, thanks for the up-vote :)